# At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I would like to plot my data with ggplot2. My data structure looks like this:

```
 str(res)
'data.frame':   1161 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ gesamt      : num  66.6 32.9 52.5 23.9 17.7 ...
 $ ITEMGROUPID : chr  "1011113" "1011113" "1011113" "1011113" ...
 $ Salesname   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Hornbach Baumarkt CZ spol. s r.o.",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ deliverydate: POSIXct, format: "2014-01-07" "2014-01-31" "2014-02-10" "2014-03-06" ...
```

I would like to facett my data with this code:

```
ggplot(data = res, aes(x = res$deliverydate, y = res$gesamt, colour = res$Salesname)) +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~res$ITEMGROUPID)
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

A reproducable example:

```
> dput(head(res))
structure(list(gesamt = c(66.6, 32.86, 52.54, 23.89, 17.74, 45.05
), ITEMGROUPID = c("1011113", "1011113", "1011113", "1011113", 
"1011113", "1011113"), Salesname = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Hornbach Baumarkt CZ spol. s r.o.", "Possling GmbH & Co. KG"
), class = "factor"), deliverydate = structure(c(1389049200, 
1391122800, 1391986800, 1394060400, 1394751600, 1395874800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("gesamt", "ITEMGROUPID", 
"Salesname", "deliverydate"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)` and `ggplot2 2.2.0`. What version are you on?

Comment: R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) and ggplot v2.1.0. I use Microsoft R client

Comment: Your example data only contains one ID and therefore it's not possible to check where facet_warp fails. btw: you dont have to add res in the facet_wrap `facet_wrap(~ITEMGROUPID)`

Comment: As @timfaber pointed out, you don't have to use the data name in your facet wrap. His solution works in ggplot version 2.1.0. Or you could just update to the newer version. Good luck!

Comment: @timfaberthank you. It was my failure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use facet\_grid correctly in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514930/how-to-use-facet-grid-correctly-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

```
ggplot(data = res, aes(x = deliverydate, y = gesamt, colour = Salesname)) +
geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ITEMGROUPID)
```